# flume-kite-morphline: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT

Tags: hadoop, jackson, flume, morphline, kite-sdk

While working on flume (1.6& 1.7) I am experiencing  the below error

```
2016-12-02 00:57:11,634 (pool-3-thread-1) [WARN - org.apache.flume.serialization.LineDeserializer.readLine(LineDeserializer.java:143)] Line length exceeds max (2048), truncating line!
2016-12-02 00:57:11,777 (pool-3-thread-1) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.source.SpoolDirectorySource$SpoolDirectoryRunnable.run(SpoolDirectorySource.java:280)] FATAL: Spool Directory source r2: { spoolDir: /home/h/flume/forex }: Uncaught exception in SpoolDirectorySource thread. Restart or reconfigure Flume to continue processing.
org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineRuntimeException: org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineRuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input within/between OBJECT entries
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@319bed83; line: 1, column: 4097]
    at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.FaultTolerance.handleException(FaultTolerance.java:73)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineHandlerImpl.process(MorphlineHandlerImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineInterceptor$LocalMorphlineInterceptor.intercept(MorphlineInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineInterceptor$LocalMorphlineInterceptor.intercept(MorphlineInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineInterceptor.intercept(MorphlineInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.flume.interceptor.InterceptorChain.intercept(InterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.processEventBatch(ChannelProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.flume.source.SpoolDirectorySource$SpoolDirectoryRunnable.run(SpoolDirectorySource.java:258)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineRuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input within/between OBJECT entries
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@319bed83; line: 1, column: 4097]
    at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdio.AbstractParser.doProcess(AbstractParser.java:98)
    at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
    at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.doProcess(AbstractCommand.java:186)
    at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineHandlerImpl.process(MorphlineHandlerImpl.java:130)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input within/between OBJECT entries
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@319bed83; line: 1, column: 4097]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1524)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWS(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2547)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:709)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer.deserializeObject(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:217)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:14)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.nextValue(MappingIterator.java:189)
    at org.kitesdk.morphline.json.ReadJsonBuilder$ReadJson.doProcess(ReadJsonBuilder.java:110)
    at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdio.AbstractParser.doProcess(AbstractParser.java:96)
    ... 17 more
```

My agent pipeline is setup to have ingested json data from a spooldir source , extracted and transformed using a morphline interceptor.

See excerpts of flume config  below

```
#GENERIC
a1.channels = mem-channel
a1.sources = r2
a1.sinks = k2 k3 

#CHANNEL
a1.channels.mem-channel.type = memory
a1.channels.mem-channel.capacity = 10000000
a1.channels.mem-channel.transactionCapacity = 1000

#SRC
a1.sources.r2.type = spooldir 
a1.sources.r2.channels = mem-channel
a1.sources.r2.spoolDir = /path/to/some/directory
a1.sources.r2.interceptors = morphline

#INTERCEPTOR
a1.sources.r2.interceptors.morphline.type = org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.MorphlineInterceptor$Builder
a1.sources.r2.interceptors.morphline.morphlineFile =/some/morphline/forex.conf
a1.sources.r2.interceptors.morphline.morphlineId = convertJsonToCSV

#SINK
a1.sinks.k2type = logger
a1.sinks.k2.channel = mem-channel

a1.sinks.k3.type = file_roll
a1.sinks.k3.channel = mem-channel
a1.sinks.k3.sink.directory = /tmp/flume
a1.sinks.k3.batchSize = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**RCA**

The answer was staring at me all the while.The issue was **not** the morphline configuration nor the input son file. 
Closer look at the flume WARNING line

```
[WARN - org.apache.flume.serialization.LineDeserializer.readLine(LineDeserializer.java:143)] Line length exceeds max (2048), truncating line!
```

gave good direction to the solution.By default spooldir source uses the `deserialiser.LINE`.It has a parameter `deserializer.maxLineLength` with default value 2048. From the Flume User Guide , this parameter is defined as

> Maximum number of characters to include in a single event. If a line exceeds this length, it is truncated, and the remaining characters on the line will appear in a subsequent event

The JSON objects could not be parsed as the data content was truncated on spooling processing which made it incomplete for the morphline to process the JSON byte array read.

**Solution**

I increased the value of `deserializer.maxLineLength` to 10000 (to be safe as my number of character from the son file could be large in future).